# How can use tf.train.batch to support padding variable length constant?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am doing practice using TensorFlow, and my code is as following:

```
a = tf.constant([[1,2,3],
               [1,2,0],
               [1,2,4],
               [1,2],
               [1,3,4,2],
               [1,2,3]])

b = tf.reshape(tf.range(12), [6,2])

num_epochs = 3
batch_size = 2
num_batches = 3

# dequeue ops
a_batched, b_batched = tt.slice_input_producer([a, b], num_epochs = num_epochs, capacity=48, shuffle=False)
aa, bb = tt.batch([a_batched, b_batched], batch_size=batch_size, dynamic_pad=True)
aa3 = tf.reduce_mean(aa)
bb3 = tf.reduce_mean(bb)
loss = tf.squared_difference(aa3, bb3)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(),
    tf.local_variables_initializer()])
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = queue_runner_impl.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
for i in range(num_batches*num_epochs):
    print sess.run(loss)
    print '='*30
coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
```

Since the variable a is with variable length, the code runs into the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "small_input_with_no_padding.py", line 16, in 
>       [1,2,3]])
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 99, in constant
>       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 376, in make_tensor_proto
>       _GetDenseDimensions(values)))
>   ValueError: Argument must be a dense tensor: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2], [1, 3, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3]] - got shape [6], but wanted [6, 3].

I want to test how can tf.train.batch pad the input with variable length. So how can I fix this error? Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a constant tensor by a variable length list which can not be converted to a dense tensor.

```
a = tf.constant([[1,2,3], [1,2,0], [1,2,4], [1,2], [1,3,4,2], [1,2,3]])
```